# Use a picklist to select the number of records to be displayed in paginator

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, pagination, standardsetcontroller

I got the following method which uses Standardset controller and currently I have assigned a size to display the number of records in each pagination section. I want to make the size a picklist and depending on the value user selects, it should paginate according to that size. How can I do this ?

```
public void stringSearchValue(){

        setCon = null; // Clears the previous search results
        if(setCon == null){
            size=20; // Records to display for every section

            if( searchStringName.length() >=3 || searchStringPostCode.length() >=3 || searchStringSPID.length() >=3 ){

                string searchquery = 'SELECT Name, Id, Postcode__c, SPID__c, OrgId__c FROM Market_Entity__c WHERE (Name LIKE \'%'+searchStringName+'%\' AND Postcode__c LIKE \'%'+searchStringPostCode+'%\' AND SPID__c LIKE \'%'+searchStringSPID+'%\') AND OrgId__c = \'SWBS\'';

                setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(searchquery));
                marketEntity = setCon.getRecords();
                setCon.setPageSize(size);
                noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();

                warningMessage = 'No Result Found';
                    if (marketEntity.size() == 0) 
                        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'No Result Found'));

            }else{
                warningMessage = 'Search text should have atleast 3 characters';
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Search text should have 3 characters on atleast one field.'));
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Created this new getter method and kept the size as it is in the mentioned method.

```
public List<SelectOption> paginatorSizeList{
        get{
            //List of select options to set the records for a certain number
            paginationSizeOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
                paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('5','5'));
                paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('10','10'));
                paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('20','20'));
                paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('50','50'));
                paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('100','100'));

                return paginationSizeOptions;
        }
        set;
    }
```

did the following VF changes,

```
<apex:actionFunction name="refreshPageSize" action="{!refreshPageSize}" status="fetchStatus2" reRender="pb"/>

<apex:selectList value="{!size}" multiselect="false" size="1" onchange="refreshPageSize();">
                                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!paginatorSizeList}"/>
                                            </apex:selectList>

<apex:outputPanel >                      
    <apex:actionStatus id="fetchStatus2" >
        <apex:facet name="start" >
        <img src="/img/loading.gif" />                    
            </apex:facet>
    </apex:actionStatus>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Found the answer in the following link, very helpful !

http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/pagination-using-standard-set-controller-salesforce/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/37161)

Comment: Added my answer !